# Recording audio while on a call?

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioplayer, avaudiorecorder, avaudiosession

I have an app that logs the decibel every second, and the decibel level is recorded even in the background when the user switches to another app, or locks the screen; however, when the user makes a call, the decibel level that is logged gets stuck at -160.00, and continues to be stuck even when the user ends the call and returns to the app.

I have a hunch this may be because the audio recording is running on one stream, and when that stream is interrupted, the stream stops and doesn't start back up again when the app is entered.

Would it make sense then, to check periodically if the decibel is being logged, and start the stream again?